# String of fixed length digits in Bogus

Tags: bogus

I did this:

```
var f = new Faker();
String.Join("", f.Random.Digits(10)
```

However, is there another method that would eliminate the 'Join' call?

Comment: What's with all the capitalized function names?

Comment: .net framework guidelines indicate Pascal casing generally for all public members.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions  If you're used to javascript, it's javascript that's wrong, not the other way around :P.

Comment: I'm used to the majority of languages, which don't use Pascal-case; I used Free Pascal in school but only briefly.

Answer (score 5):

Wow. Sorry for the late reply, but yes there's a way to do this in [**Bogus**](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

```cs
void Main()
{
   var f = new Faker();
   var numberString = f.Random.ReplaceNumbers("##########");
   numberString.Dump();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2166951396
```

By the way, thanks for using **Bogus**!

Comment: What is `Dump` ? Valid using `Randomizer` ?